# 2.5D rendering time in QGIS

Tags: qgis, time, rendering, graphics, 3d-map

I have QGIS V 2.18.18

I am practicing making 3D maps and decided to do a simple population density 3D map for the states and territories of India. 
I have a shapefile that contains 36 features(States and territories) with their respective densities.

I used the 2.5D option in the layer styling, and chose pop_density/1000 as the height.

Now it is rendering, but it is taking a really really long time to render the map.

It has been 15 minutes and less than 1/3rd of the map has been rendered.

I have an Intel Corei7 2.9 GhZ processor, 32 gb of memory, and and NVIDIA quadro 1200M on my laptop. So I do not think there could be problem with my computer configuration.

Should I be checking some configuration, or changing any settings for it to render faster?